# Springboot and weird output upon request

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

When developing a Spring boot Mvc application with a simple JSON controller, upon request I receive a weird `Received 1` output in my terminal, for production I would like that this output is not shown as it doesn't benefit at all and just fills my log file with unwanted data.

Anybody who know how I can remove the output and where I can read up on why I see `Received 1`

This would be some of the content of the controller class and I've search through the files with grep to see where `Received 1` comes from.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getServicesForRole", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<List<Service>> getServicesForRole(@RequestParam(value = "role") String role) {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(aurora.getServices(role));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("getServiceForRole failed " + e.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
    }
}
```

`2017-04-26 10:49:13.444  INFO 106361 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 17 ms
Received 1
Received 1`

Comment: Maybe post the full line of output...

Comment: Yes forgot in the haste of writing the question, added.

Comment: I would look for something that does a `System.out.println("Received"` and not specific that message.